# Unable to call methods of a java class from the activity class

Tags: java, android

i am making an sms application where the user types in the contact and the message and then clicks the button butenc. The button has to send the variable phone number and message to another java class where a method receives the data and manipulates it. The Ecc java file is a standalone java class that is linked to various other java classes for operations on the message. I some times get a stackoverflow error and when i manipulate a few things in the code, the application runs and when i click the enc button nothing happens but when i click the send button the message is sent. I am sure i am having a problem in passing the variable to the Ecc class. I went through various questions here on OS but none of them solve the issue. The changes i make give either of the problems i mentioned above. How do i get over this problem?

SMSTest.java(main android activity)

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SMSTest extends Activity 
{
    public final static String SMS_Message = "com.example.SMSTest.MESSAGE";
public final static String SMS_Phone = "com.example.SMSTest.MESSAGE";
Button btnSendSMS;
Button btnEnc;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
```

Ecc ecc;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnEnc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnc);
    txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

    ecc=new Ecc(this);

    /*
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here..."); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    */

    btnEnc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString(); 
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0){
                System.out.println("details verified");
                ecc.recv(phoneNo, message);    
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Ecc started", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString(); 
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();               
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });        
}

//---sends a SMS message to another device---
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")    
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{      
    /*
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    */

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic      failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                  
            }
        }
    },new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
    }  
}
```

Here my other class (Ecc.java)

```
package com.example.smsTest;
import java.util.*;
public class Ecc{

//code
private SMSTest smsTest;


// Constructor
public Ecc(SMSTest smsTest) {
    this.smsTest = smsTest;
}


public void recv(String phn, String smsg){

/*performs manipulation on phn and msg taken 
from the main activity using various other 
java files linked with it and again sends it 
back to themaina ctivities sendSMS method*/
smsTest.sendSMS(pnh,smsg)
}

//code
}
```

my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Enter the phone number of recipient"
    />     
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    />
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:text="Message"
    />     
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="150px"
    android:gravity="top"         
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ecc" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send SMS"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

when i click send button the message is being sent but when i click ecc the ecc class load start...

here is my logcat

```
02-26 13:04:36.337: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:36.447: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:36.447: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:36.797: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:36.797: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.077: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.117: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.247: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.247: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.318: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.391: I/Choreographer(1265): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 13:04:37.416: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.416: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.427: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.427: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.437: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-26 13:04:37.447: W/Trace(1265): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: what is your problem, where you are getting error, can you post your logcat error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate an `Ecc` object, it creates an `SMSTest` object, thich creates an `Ecc` object which creates an `SMSTest` object, ad infinitum. That produces a stack overflow.

This can't be right.

You need something like this in your `Ecc` class:

```
// Reference to the SMSTest instance
private SMSTest smsTest;

// Constructor
public Ecc(SMSTest smsTest) {
    this.smsTest = smsTest;
}
```

In `SMSTest`, change

```
Ecc ecc=new Ecc();
```

to

```
Ecc ecc; // This variable gets initialized in onCreate()
```

Then, in `SMSTest.onCreate()` do:

```
ecc=new Ecc(this);
```

Comment: THank you so much for this but i have problem with the button now. I do not get the stackoverflow error but when i click the button it doesnot do anything

Comment: Add some logging or set breakpoints and see if your `onClick()` method is getting called.

Comment: i checked that the method is being called but ecc class doesnot load. i edited the question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **StackoverFlow**!

Your approach is wrong.

Activity is never created this way. `SMSTest smstest=new SMSTest();`

Its better passing a reference to this activity when you create your `Ecc` object and then use that reference to give a call to any method in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create static method in java class and call that in activity with class name.And you can do vice versa.means if you want to call activity method in java class then make that method static in activity and call that method by actvity name.

Comment: In this case a lot of the library methods do not work as they are not static by them selves.